# How to create tags input/label which are directly linked with URL using Ajax or something

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create tags/labels for an application. structure when i select a checkbox from the sidebar than selected value should be shown as a tag at the top with a `x` icon so the user can click on `x` and that value remove from url and get back to the previous structure.

HTML

```
<form class="motor-form" action="<?= base_url() ?>/frontend/view">
    <div class="col-xs-12 search-box-style">
                                        <?php
                                        $category = array(
                                            1 => 'Coupe',
                                            2 => 'Crossover',
                                            3 => 'Hard Top Convertible',
                                            4 => 'Hatchback',
                                            5 => 'Pick Up Truck',
                                            6 => 'Sedan',
                                            7 => 'Soft Top Convertible',
                                            8 => 'Sports Car',
                                            9 => 'SUV',
                                            10 => 'Utility Truck',
                                            11 => 'Van',
                                            12 => 'Wagon',
                                            13 => 'Other'
                                        );
                                        foreach ($category as $k => $v) {
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="body_type-items">
                                                <?php
                                                if (isset($_GET['body_type']) && in_array($k, @$_GET['body_type'])) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="body_type[]" checked=""
                                                           value="<?= $k; ?>"
                                                           data-value="<?php echo strtolower($v); ?>">
                                                    <?php
                                                } else {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="body_type[]" value="<?= $k; ?>"
                                                           data-value="<?php echo strtolower($v); ?>">
                                                    <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>

                                                <?= $v; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="body_type-no-result-found"></div>
</form>
```

Script

```
     $(".makes-search").bind('input', function () {
                var makes_value = $(this).val();
                $('.makes-items').hide();
                $('.makes-no-result-found').hide();
                $(".makes-items > input[data-value^='" + makes_value.toLowerCase() + "']").parent().show();

                if ($(".makes-search").val() == "") {
                    $(".makes-items").show();
                }
                if ($('.makes-items').is(':visible') == false) {
                    $('.makes-no-result-found').text("No Result Found '" + makes_value + "'").show();
                } else {
                    $('.makes-no-result-found').hide();
                }
            });
  $(".motor-form").change(function () {
            $(".motor-form").submit();
        });
    });
```

Tags which works fine but don't know how can i connect with the url so and when the user click it should disappear from URL

```
<?php
$body_type = array(
    1 => 'Coupe',
    2 => 'Crossover',
    3 => 'Hard Top Convertible',
    4 => 'Hatchback',
    5 => 'Pick Up Truck',
    6 => 'Sedan',
    7 => 'Soft Top Convertible',
    8 => 'Sports Car',
    9 => 'SUV',
    10 => 'Utility Truck',
    11 => 'Van',
    12 => 'Wagon',
    13 => 'Other'
);
foreach (@$_GET['body_type'] as $color) { ?>
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><?= array_key_exists($getUrlVal, $body_type) ? $body_type[$getUrlVal] : null ?>
    </button>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where's your AJAX attempt? Put your CSS, JavaScript, and PHP on Separate pages from your HTML. That way the CSS and JavaScript are cached. Use JavaScript to send to PHP then back from PHP to JavaScript *(that's AJAX)*. Personally, I like the `$.post()` method, if using jQuery. `echo json_encode($assocArray)` from the PHP.

Comment: i added my ajax attempt in script section